# CakePHP 2.2.1 - Showing CakePHP error on form - custom validation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have an array of errors when I manually validate form:

```
 $this->CalculationElement->set($this->request->data);
        if($this->CalculationElement->validates()){
            WHEN OK...

        }else{
        debug($this->CalculationElement->invalidFields());
            die;
        }
```

So, with ->invalidFields() I get array of errors... How can I display them at the bottom of the inputs just like CakePHP does it on $this->Model->save();?

I can $this->Model->set() them, but that's, again, just an array of errors in VIEW.

Comment: It should already work if you're using the FormHelper

Comment: you should NOT be using invalidFields() in combination with validates() or save() - or you validate twice which will potentially screw everything up. use `$this->CalculationElement->validationErrors` (not a method) to get the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if ($this->CalculationElement->validates()){
    //WHEN OK...
}
else
{
    $this->validateErrors($this->CalculationElement);
    $this->render();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case it seems that you have to add all classes and messages manually in the view.

the input itself gets the class "form-error"
right after that input you have to create a div with the class "error-message"

```
<div class="error-message">$_your_error_message_from_the_array</div>
```

this should do the trick, i think.